# Playframework parse request parameters and keys

Tags: java, routes, http-headers, playframework-2.0

I am using play framework with java

I would like to ask you a question, if it is possible some way to get from http request(get and post) or http.context used route parameters.

Like that from url:

```
  /ru/149/home.html
    param1 = ru;
    param2 = 45;
```

I need to get all parameters of opened url in java. 
I tried to parse result from http.request but now success there.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: How does your route look like in `conf/routes`? You can directly use the action method parameters.

Comment: GET  /:lng/:id/login.html                                                                                       @controllers.user.LoginController.blank(lng: String, id: Integer)

Comment: Maybe I misunderstood your question. You want to get `ru` (`lng`) and `149` (`id`)? Why do you not use the method parameters in your action `blank`?

Comment: I want to get opened view url parameters in java to been able to change only language and all other parameters would be the same.

Comment: What do you mean with _opened view url parameters_?